# Python: Calculate score with binary target data

Tags: python, regression, classification

I have some data giving whether or not some influencer is a bot. Of course the target data is in binary values. I need to use this whole data to calculate a score for the influencer rather than a direct prediction. So here I am stuck with three options with no definite answer that I could find for which one to use. The data is obtained from Instagram API and I am to experiment with some features or pick some from work of others.

1. Should I train a classifier and remove sigmoid function from the last layer to get continuous values and use as a score; is this possible to do in python?
2. Is there a way to train a regressor with the binary target data and would that be suitable?
3. Or am I just left with an option to create a formula like that of engagement for the score with what information I have?

Please guide as I am a newbie and now completely stuck.

Answer (score 2):

This exactly what a [Logistic regression](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/linear_model.html#logistic-regression) does - it calculates the probability of an input being class 1.

Say you chose your labels to be `[bot,no-bot] = [1,0]` then it gives you the probability of an input being a bot.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I was assuming that every classifier must have an output of binary values. Can something please be said about linearity in the probabilities outputted.

Comment: I don't think I understand the question about linearity? You'll get one probability (for each sample) which is the probability of the sample being in class 1